# How can I improve suggested tag wiki edit when there is no option to improve?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

Screen shot shows (on top left) I can "Approve, reject or improve edits suggested by users"

But how do I improve a tag wiki suggested edit? I have no option to improve it, only to approve or reject or skip

[image: tag wiki suggestion]

I suspect just the text needs updating.

Or should there be an option (button) to improve it as we have when reviewing posts?

Comment: I think I actually used the improve edits link a few times. Might be rep capped at 20k?

Comment: Yes @Hennes, I have used it but never when reviewing a tag update.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/privileges/trusted-user 20k is required to edit tag wikis.

Comment: Fine @David but then it shouldn't suggest I can ...